Cannot get URLSessionTaskDelegate#willBeginDelayedRequest to be called, regardless
No matter what I do, willBeginDelayedRequest is not called. The other delegate calls work perfectly.
Note that this is not even in a background capable app, it's the simple case ...

run the app
kill internet connectivity
now send your api call or whatever
see message "A"
later turn on internet
see message "C"
:( you will never see message "B"

I've seen this behavior in many projects. How to get willBeginDelayedRequest working??
Delegate ...
class Main: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {

code ..
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, taskIsWaitingForConnectivity task: URLSessionTask) {
    print("(A) works perfectly - phone was offline when task was started")
}

// Doesn't seem to work ...
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willBeginDelayedRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.DelayedRequestDisposition, URLRequest?) -> Void) {
    print("(B) this is never called, even when the command completes perfectly :/")
}

setting the delegate ...
let cfg = URLSessionConfiguration.default
cfg.waitsForConnectivity = true
let task = URLSession(configuration: cfg).dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
    ...
    ...
    print("(C) after net restored, this runs flawlessly")
}
task.delegate = ..
task.resume()


"Note that this is not even in a background capable app" contradicts the discussion on this method: "This method is called when a background session task with a delayed start time". The other one (the one "working") says "It is never called for background sessions because waitsForConnectivity is ignored for those sessions.", so this behavior seems normal.

ah!  I guess you have solved the puzzle @Larme  !!  Thanks. Perhaps worth putting in an answer for googlers ?  It would seem there is NO call to let you know it has "begun again" in the non-background case- do you happen to know if that's the case?  Ts again

Are you looking for Reachability (ie know when you get back "internet connection")?

cheers @Larme no, we use that in most projects.  When i create a URLSessionDataTask , it will tell me (obviously via the delegate) when/if there has been a problem sending. I want it to tell me when it has again made the connection (and/or, subtly, when it again tries to and/or believes it is now possible for it to try to).

{You can kind of do this in a sloppy way with .progress in some cases but it's not really the answer.)

The important part of your scenario: Not in background.
The doc of urlSession(_:task:willBeginDelayedRequest:completionHandler:) states:

This method is called when a background session task with a delayed
start time (as set with the earliestBeginDate property) is ready to
start. This delegate method should only be implemented if the request
might become stale while waiting for the network load and needs to be
replaced by a new request. For loading to continue, the delegate must
call the completion handler, passing in a disposition that indicates
how the task should proceed. Passing the
URLSession.DelayedRequestDisposition.cancel disposition is equivalent
to calling cancel() on the task directly.

The doc of urlSession(_:taskIsWaitingForConnectivity:) states:

This method is called, at most, once per task, and only if
connectivity is initially unavailable. It is never called for
background sessions because waitsForConnectivity is ignored for
those sessions.

So this should explains why you get URLSessionTaskDelegate method urlSession(_:taskIsWaitingForConnectivity:) is called in your test, but not urlSession(_:task:willBeginDelayedRequest:completionHandler:).
